# Crystal Reports: append spaces to string

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a field in my report that needs to have a length of 40. If the string is not of that length I need to append some space.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something along the lines of

if length({yourfieldname here}) < 40
then
   {yourfieldnamehere} + space(40 - length({yourfieldnamehere}))
else
{yourfieldnamehere}

Comment: should point out that that goes in the formula for a formula field you define yourself lol!

Answer (score 2):

Append 40 blanks to the variable and take the first 40 characters of the resulting string.

Something like

```
mid( (yourfield + space(40)), 1, 40)
```

should work.